# REXML::Document.new take a simple string as good doc?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, rexml

I would like to check if the xml is valid. So, here is my code

```
require 'rexml/document'
begin

  def valid_xml?(xml)
    REXML::Document.new(xml)
  rescue REXML::ParseException
    return nil
  end

  bad_xml_2=%{aasdasdasd}
  if(valid_xml?(bad_xml_2) == nil)
    puts("bad xml")
    raise "bad xml"
  end
  puts("good_xml")
rescue Exception => e
  puts("exception" + e.message)
end
```

and it returns good_xml as result. Did I do something wrong? It will return bad_xml if the string is

```
bad_xml = %{
     <tasks>
      <pending>

      <entry>Grocery Shopping</entry>
      <done>
      <entry>Dry Cleaning</entry>
     </tasks>}
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd recommend using [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org), as it's the defacto standard for XML/HTML parsing in Ruby. Using it to parse a malformed document:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML('<xml><foo><bar></xml>')
doc.errors # => [#<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: Opening and ending tag mismatch: bar line 1 and xml>, #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: Premature end of data in tag foo line 1>, #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: Premature end of data in tag xml line 1>]
```

If I parse a document that is well-formed:

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML('<xml><foo/><bar/></xml>')
doc.errors # => []
```

Answer (score 0):

`REXML` treats a simple string as a valid XML with no root node:

```
xml = REXML::Document.new('aasdasdasd')
# => <UNDEFINED> ... </>
```

It *does not* however treat illegal XML (with mismatching tags, for example) as a valid XML, and throws an exception.

```
REXML::Document.new(bad_xml)
# REXML::ParseException: #<REXML::ParseException: Missing end tag for 'done' (got "tasks")
```

It is missing an end-tag to `<done>` - so it is not valid.